# I want to send image from my computer to server

Tags: python, http, file-upload, server, python-requests

I want to send image with raspberry pi 3 model B.
Using the requests library, I can send text like this code here.
But I don't know how to send image to a server.
I need help to send it using requests library.
If there another way or another library please tell me.

```
import requests

payload = {'fisrtName': 'kerolos' , 'lastName': 'Shenouda'}

r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post' , data = payload)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Is the server is yours? Do you have acces do the server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic). 
[Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)
You can find a ton of good resources on the internet, and possibly many questions on SO that deal with similar problems. In your case, a quick google search for [upload image python requests](https://www.google.com/search?q=upload+image+python+requests) gives you tons of good tutorials.

Comment: It is my server, so I have access to the server.